# Rewriter does not work

Tags: asp.net, regex, mod-rewrite

I have a web site with some sub domain.  For rewriting, I use this code in my web.config

```
<if header="HTTP_HOST" match="^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$"> 
    <set property="subdomain" value="$1"/> 
    <set property="domain" value="$2"/> 
    <set property="tld" value="$3"/> 
    <rewrite url="~/Default.aspx" to="~/userPage.aspx?pagename=${subdomain}&defaultpage=yes" processing="stop"/> 
    <!--<rewrite url="~/Default.aspx" to="~/Default.aspx" processing="stop"/>--> 
</if>
```

When I test website with this address everything is good: http://www.sub1.mysite.com/coHome.aspx

But when I want to test this address: http://www.sub1.mysite.com

...the rewrite doesn't work.

Comment: Could you expand a little on what you mean when you say that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Against what `match` parameter works ? http://www.sub1.mysite.com/coHome.aspx OR www.sub1.mysite.com ? Can you show us what subdomain, domain and tld properties contain when the rewriter works.

Comment: hi alex.sub1 is dynmic and read in db.